# Subsequent WCF calls cause blocking with unknown reason and finally cause TimeoutException?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm not sure why it could be so. But I'm sure if using asynchronous calls, there won't be no blocking.

The scenario here is I have 2 WCF method calls, the first one will trigger some callback call to the client (using `CallbackContract`). The second one is just a normal WCF method call (even an empty method having no code at all).

The methods content is not important, here is just some kind of pseudo code:

```
public void FirstMethod(){
    //some logic here...
    //here I use some Callback method to client side
    clientCallbackInterface.SomeMethod();//commenting this out won't 
    //cause any blocking.
}

public void SecondMethod(){
    //this is even empty
}

//call the 2 methods synchronously in a sequence
client.FirstMethod();
client.SecondMethod();
```

Without calling the `SecondMethod`, it runs just fine. If using asynchronous calls, it also runs just fine. Or if I comment out the call (using the  client callback interface), it will also run just fine.

At the time the exception `TimeoutException` is thrown, it shows that the method `SecondMethod` is actually done and in the phase of responding to client.

The ServiceBehavior has `InstanceContextMode` of `PerSession` and `ConcurrencyMode` of `Multiple`.

I hope someone here has experienced with this and understands the cause behind this issue.

**UPDATE**:

- I've just tried a new thing by setting `ConcurrencyMode` to `Single` instead and it also run just fine. So I would like to know more on how to make it run fine with `ConcurrencyMode` of `Multiple`?

**UPDATE**:

I'm really confused about what is wrong here, in fact there is some old code which does not even use `CallbackBehavior` and it simply works fine with `ConcurrencyMode` of `Multiple`. While my code need `CallbackBehavior` and it failed at the second time of executing the 2 methods. Here is the minimum code I can post, I've tried it and the method content does not really matter, it can be just empty:

```
//the service interface
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMyClient), SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
public interface IMyService
{   
    bool MyMethod();
}
//the client callback interface
public interface IMyClient 
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OnSomething(SomeEventArgs e);
}
//the service class
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]        
[CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{ 
   static Dictionary<ClientInfo, IMyClient> clients; 
   static Dictionary<ClientInfo, IMyClient> Clients
    {
        get
        {
            if (clients == null)
                clients = new Dictionary<ClientInfo, IMyClient>();
            return clients;
        }
    }
   static void raiseEvents(Action<IMyClient> raiser, params Guid[] toClients)
    {
        if (raiser == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("raiser cannot be null.");

        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(o => {
            lock (clients)
            {
                //ClientInfo is just some class holding some info about 
                //the client such as its ClientGuid
                Func<KeyValuePair<ClientInfo, IMyClient>, bool> filter = c => toClients.Length == 0 || toClients.Any(e => e == c.Key.ClientGuid);
                foreach (var client in Clients.Where(filter).Select(e => e.Value))
                {
                    raiser(client);
                }
            }
        }));                            
    }
   public bool MyMethod(){
       //do nothing before trying to trigger some callback to the client
       raiseEvents(e => e.OnSomething(new SomeEventArgs()));
       return true;
   }
}
```

The `raiseEvents` method above in fact is what I followed the old code (as I mentioned which works just fine), as before it looks much simpler like this (and also does not work):

```
static void raiseEvents(Action<IMyClient> raiser, params Guid[] toClients)
    {
        if (raiser == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("raiser cannot be null.");            
        Func<KeyValuePair<ClientInfo, IPosClient>, bool> filter = c => toClients.Length == 0 || toClients.Any(e => e == c.Key.ClientGuid);
        foreach (var client in Clients.Where(filter).Select(e => e.Value))
        {
           Task.Run(() => raiser(client));
        }                 
    }
```

One possible difference between the old code and the one I'm writing is in the configuration file but I'm not really sure which could lead to this issue. In fact I've tried cloning the configuration as much as I can (about the `<behaviors>`).

As initially described there are 2 methods involved here. However this time I have just 1 method as in the code. The first time it's called OK, the next time calling it will freeze the UI (like as having some deadlock). Calling it is just simple when you have the client proxy class (which is auto-generated by the Add Service Reference wizard):

```
//this is put in some Execute method of some Command (in WPF)
myServiceClient.MyMethod();
```

In fact I can work-around this issue by using the `async` version of `MyMethod` or simply put that call in a thread but the old code does not need to do that and I'm really curious about why it works the first time but keeps freezing (until `TimeoutException` is thrown) the next time.

Comment: What is the nature of client application? WPF/WinForms or some web page? How to you obtain channel/proxy on the client side?

Comment: @IgorLabutin the client app is a WPF app and I use the Add Service  Reference wizard to gen the client's classes for accessing/calling the service's methods. Thank you for your response and I hope you have some idea to solve this issue.

Comment: Read here (at the end): http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,b891610a-6b78-4b54-b9a6-4ec81c82b7c0.aspx. Most likely you invoke that from UI thread in your WPF application, and callback is then also dispacthed to UI thread. Try decorate your callback object with [CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, UseSynchronizationContext=false)]

Comment: @Evk yes using that trick seems to make it work the first time (like as when using ConcurrencyMode of Single) but if I try calling the 2 methods the next time, it goes freezing again (even with ConcurrencyMode of Single). If I comment out the line calling back to the client, then it just works fine no matter how many times I call the 2 methods. This is going to confuse me now.

Comment: Well you need to provide minimal example then, so that we can see what is wrong there. Or just provide more code (your service definition, callback object, how and where exactly do you call service).

Comment: @Evk more details have been added, however as I said the scenario here is very simple (almost some kind of basic example about duplex communication in WCF). I hope you could figure out what's wrong here, thanks.

Comment: But your CallbackBehavior attribute is applied to the wrong class - it should be applied to the _implementation_ of callback contract, that is to implementation of IMyClient. Carefully read remarks and examples here -  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.callbackbehaviorattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. You also didn't provide client implementaiton, only server, and client implementation is what is most important here.

Comment: @Evk you have saved my life - that's what I did wrong after trying `CallbackBehavior` as you had suggested before. Please add your answer with some info which you think is useful for other readers and so that I can accept it. Once again thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, WCF will execute callback on current SynchronizationContext. That means when you call WCF service from UI thread in for example WPF or WinForms application - callback will also be executed on UI thread. But this thread is already blocked by your call to service and so your call to service and service's callback to client will deadlock. First - don't call remote services from UI thread, that bad from user experience point of view anyway (your interface will freeze while waiting for result of the call). But if you still do that, at least tell WCF to not use current synhronization context for callbacks, by using CallbackBehavior attribute:

```
[CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, UseSynchronizationContext=false)]
class Callback : IClientCallback
{

}
```